# HttpServletResponse getStatus() method throws compilation error that method does not exist

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I have configured maven with 3.1.0 for javax.servlet-api dependency, Spring with 4.3.7 and tomcat 8 as server, when I try to access the method response.getStatus() it throws compile-time exception that method that does not exist with the HttpServletResponse Interface,

What Could be the problem on this, I suspect the problem that could be in the side dependency Version

Comment: Can you copy paste error stacktrace

Comment: compiler says that getStatus() method is not defined in HttpServletResponse Interface